На какие пины нужно ставить провода, чтоб запитать этот вентилятор от Arduino
У меня есть ненужный вентилятор от корпуса ПК и я хочу из него сделать обдувалку. У меня есть Arduino с разными пинами питания, от вентилятора исходят 3 провода. Если что, ардуино - ATMEGA2560 от keyestudio. К среде разработки Arduino подключается. Заранее говорю, все 5V - пины постоянно выдают напряжение, а вентилятору нужно 12V, 0.16А. Ардуино питается от компа, так что мощности на 12V будет хватать. Куда какой из проводов в какой пин надо поставить, чтобы вентилятор заработал?


Проще всего вывести провода от БП и подключить вентилятор к ним напрямую, например с кнопкой, без Ардуино. Если надо именно с Ардуино, до полуампера (кажется на USB такое ограничение) и не можете вывести +12в, то поищите boost конвертер, для поднятия напряжения с 5в до 12в. В любом случае, управлять вентилятором будет правильнее через транзистор (или реле), а не напрямую с ног Ардуино. Т.е. питание вентилятора отдельно, управление питанием Ардуиной - отдельно.
У вас на фото не видно проводов самого венитлятора, но питание вентилятора скорее всего стандартное - черный земля, красный провод питание +12, а желтый не нужен, это сигнал с датчика оборотов.

провода вентилятора закрыты пальцем. цвета там скорее красный черный желтый

@eri да, похоже.

Если нужна регулировка оборотов, то нужен или вентилятор с 4 пинами или транзисторный ключ.


Так-то регулировать обороты можно и на 2-проводном и на 3-проводном, просто меняя напряжение. Не обязательно транзистором (если КПД не важен)

@Kromster а как вы ардуину подключите без транзистора?)

Например через реле (в т.ч. твердотельное), или разориться и моторный шильд взять. Просто по себе знаю, что транзисторы могут казаться сложными и непонятными (особенно весь зоопарк из типов и разновидностей).

Реле не может регулировать напряжение. А твердотельное работает на переменном токе в основном

Рекомендую мосфетный модуль с готовой обвязкой

Делители на резисторах плюс реле для выбора.

ну хоть мотор не киловатный))) делители на резисторах на индуктивную нагрузку... мосфет проще в разы

Конечно проще. Мой поинт собственно в том, что есть 1 дорожка хорошая асфальтовая, но и другие проселочные менее хорошие тоже есть, если например у человека аллергия на асфальт. А касательно вопроса, он изначально кривой, запитать вентилятор напрямую от ардуино нормально нельзя, тем более сказать какие провода куда подключить, чтобы из 5в получить 12в ))
